# React app keeps sending multiple request on its own

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, web-applications, axios, asynchronous-javascript

I'm new to react and I'm trying to build a Weather App for my project. It keeps sending the request to the API I'm using which is OpenWeatherMap API.
I'm using Axios to send the request.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';  
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);
  const APIKEY = <APIKEY>;

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async position=>{
        await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=${APIKEY}`)
        .then(response=>{
          setData(response.data);
        }).catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
        })
      }
    )
  }, []);
  
  console.log(data);
  return<div>hello</div>
}


export default App;
```

I tried using class components it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Sounds like expected behaviour if the `window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` is triggered it will send a request, right?

Comment: btw how do you know it keeps sending the requests? if it's because of the `console.log(data)` that will be logged everytime the component function is executed, that doesn't mean the data changed, if you only want logs because something changed then wrap it with useEffect

Comment: I treied making it getCurrentPosition but it still does the same

Comment: how do you know it keeps sending the requests?

Comment: Through the network tab in chrome developer tools, it keeps calling the API and it further keeps console.logging the data repeatedly.

Comment: I mean that data is repeatedly logged I just explained. That doesn't mean data changed. That it is in the network tab is weird to be honest, I made a little test and couldn't reproduce it. Can you make a little codesandbox or something?

Comment: Here you go:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-taussig-zg4o0?file=/src/App.js

See how it sends multiple requests. I've figured that it's because geolocation keeps triggering and i tried controlling it through if else but it didn't stop.

Comment: The codesandbox seems emtpy/default to me. This only gives one log for me. Not multiple ones. https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-moon-s2u7r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey thanks!
It got better, it doesn't ruthlessly send an infinite amount of requests now but it still sends multiple requests, check your codesandbox link once. I updated the code there.

Comment: is your issue fixed?

Comment: No it keeps sending requests again when I try to return or log the data